# Check if a worksheet contains any vba code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a code that it is able to check if a worksheet contains any VBA code inside. In fact, I would like to have all worksheets empty of any VBA code.

This check will be done through another VBA code of course.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just save the file as a .xlsx then you can't have any code in it... The only way you can check for code programatically involves turning on some security settings that you really shouldn't be changing unless you _really_ know what you're doing.

Comment: This solution is not possible because in my environment, we can't block user to create any VBA code. 
*really* ? I'm ready to learn how to set security for that :o)

Comment: How would you invoke your checking routine? Having your Excel running, start your VBA-routine by button or whatever, and that opens other Excel files to examine them and says "yes, has code" or "no, has no code" in the end?

Comment: In fact, in the personal workbook of each user, I have implemented a check code that opens other Excel files to examine them (quality check) and indeed, I would like that this check code may said "This Excel file have VBA code" or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you Tick "Trust access to the VBA project object model" under Macro-trust settings:

```
Sub CheckForCode()
Dim comp As Object, x As Long
    For Each comp In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
        With comp.CodeModule
            x = x + .CountOfLines
        End With
    Next
    If x > 0 Then MsgBox x & " Lines of VBA-code"
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect ! It is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for your help !